# VBA-excel paste chart as a picture

Tags: excel, vba, charts, paste

I am creating various charts from the same source. I would like to be able to cut paste with vba each chart as a picture. Does anyone know the right code?

I tried with this but it does not work:

```
Range("B21:C22").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Graphs'!$B$21:$C$22")
ActiveChart.ChartType = xl3DPie
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
```

Comment: By not works do you mean it just does nothing or you get an error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I always find copying charts confusing, but this does what you want, I think, and doesn't use any `Selects`, which is always nice.

```
Sub CreateAndCopyChart()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cht As Chart

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Graphs")
Set cht = ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
With cht
    .SetSourceData ws.Range("$B$21:$C$22")
    .ChartType = xl3DPie
    .ChartArea.Copy
End With
ws.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
cht.Parent.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: It work great! Do you know how can I also delete the former chart?

Comment: Use `cht.Parent.delete`.  See my edit.  This is because the `Chart` is contained in a `ChartObject`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Range("A1:A8").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$8")
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy


Range("A20").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, but it does not work. The chart pasted is not a picture.

Answer (score 0):

A bit slow but lets you convert charts to pictures. I use this to create reports (in a prior step I copy charts from another tab, where the original charts are created)

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Select 
Selection.Copy                        'copy charts 
Range("A1").Select                    'choose destination
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select     'paste as pictures
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete       'delete charts (leaving just pictures)
```

Comment: Can you add a short description?